# Reflection and how to handle enums

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I want to use something similar as:

```
object ob;
            var props = ob.GetType().GetProperties();

            List<Element> list = new List<Element>();
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(String))
                    list.Add(makeStringProperty(prop));
                else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                    list.Add(makeIntProperty(prop));
                else
                {
                }
            }
```

which adds something to the given list for every property in a given object. Now I want to add a clause for also adding enum-variables, including getting all its values by Enum.GetValues() f.e..
That would be easy for any one given enum, but I want this to be generic for every possible enum,
so for example if ob would have:

```
enum Weather {
sunny,
rainy,
cloudy
}
Weather weather = sunny;

enum Places {
beach,
mall,
home
}
Places place = beach;
```

I would be able to get both variables themselves AND all the values of both Enums.
Of course I can't directly check typeof(Enum) or anything.
Does someone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something like

```
typeof(Weather).GetFields()
```

or

```
ob.GetType().GetFields()
```

if you want to use reflection directly on an `enum` type. The members of an `enum` are a kind of `static` fields.

But you can also use

```
Enum.GetValues(ob.GetType())
```

In any case, if there's doubt, you should check if it is an enum or not first:

```
var typeOfOb = ob.GetType();
if (typeOfOb.IsEnum)
{
  // use Enum.GetValues(typeOfOb) here
}
```

Note: `System.Type` is the class used for both a type determined compile-time, like `typeof(Weather)`, and a type determined run-time, like `ob.GetType()`. So you can use both as an argument to the `GetValues(System.Type)` static method.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(prop.PropertyType.IsEnum)
{
    var values = Enum.GetValues(prop.PropertyType);
}
```